# Fast and Memory efficient alternative to map

Tags: dictionary, go, memory-management

I am writing a program to among other things identify and count unique entry in a large table file (in the order of GB compressed). My current approach constitute in recording every entry name in a large `map[string]uint` and discount my count when I found a repeated entry. This works fine but when running my program allocated 8GB of RAM and I wish to reduce this footprint.

I've look into Key-Value databases to store my data, because they allow pagination into file and reduce memory footprint. Unfortunately, running some benchmarks I found most databases had even higher footprint and much slower performance. Do you have any suggestions?

```
BenchmarkMapRegister-4            500000              4678 ns/op             134 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkInsertBolt-4                100          23396720 ns/op           16524 B/op         50 allocs/op
BenchmarkInsertKV-4                10000            411216 ns/op
BenchmarkInsertGKVlite-4           30000             56059 ns/op             184 B/op          5 allocs/op
BenchmarkInsertBunt-4             100000             12795 ns/op             515 B/op          8 allocs/op
BenchmarkInsertBigCache-4         300000              4132 ns/op
BenchmarkInsertLevelDB-4           50000             28036 ns/op             497 B/op         10 allocs/op
PASS
```

P.S. I don't need to keep track of my keys, just be able to identify if it was previously recorded.

Comment: What is the length of the strings, are repeats frequent and do you care about disk space? A simple first step might be to hash the keys if they are long. If repeats are infrequent you might record the keys in a bloom filter, storing only the repeats and running a second pass to catch the first hits. If the distribution is highly skewed you might partition the map into multiple parts based on the count, effectively shunting off the less accessed parts to lower cache levels and disk.

Comment: Map *are* fast and memory-efficient. Large amounts of data will take large amounts of memory. @doynax, Go's maps already hash keys internally.

Comment: @Adrian: I was referring to using a cryptographic hash function and storing that instead. Squeeze the strings in a fixed-width space while maintaining a negligible probability of collision. As for memory a judicious use of disk storage (external algorithms) may allow reduction of RAM usage while maintaining reasonable performance. Furthermore the application only calls for the repeated records to actually be stored, which may only be a small part of the data. Hence the suggestion of a compact but lossy boom-filter as a pre-pass, then resolving false-positives.

Comment: Agree with a bloom/cuckoo filter, definite possibility for a big advantage. A cryptographic hash makes even less sense. The maps already use a hash, they're already squeezed into a fixed-width space; there's no advantage to it being a *secure* hash, it'll only be slower. Besides, there's no guarantee that the hashes, fixed-width though they may be, would actually be *shorter* than what's being hashed - they could *increase* space requirements.

Comment: @Adrian: The point was to omit storing the string at all, only relying on the hash digest and the strength of the hash function to render the probability collision acceptably low. Hence the question about the typical length of the strings, it is a loss if the average string is narrower than the substitute hash code.

Comment: *If* the average string is longer than the hash length, *and* memory is a bigger bottleneck than CPU, then yes, it *might* be beneficial to store hashes rather than strings. A fast hash would still be far more efficient than a crypto hash though.

Comment: @Adrian: Well, a memory bottleneck is the premise of the question. A fast hash may certainly work, I was just concerned of a wider key length may be required to reach the target false-positive rate with a lower quality function. Oh, and it perhaps also worth noting that a B-tree would be traditional data structure for external storage without random access if squeezing the data set into RAM proves infeasible.